# PHP prevent results from being printed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am working with an AWS SES library to be able to make a form functional.

The problem is that I am not used to work with php, and when I click on submit to send the form, the print_r function prints the results of the mail.

I don't want these results to be printed, and if I remove the print_r function the form is not submitted.
Does anyone know of a function to execute the php code but not print it? Thank you very much!

CODE: [image]

Comment: Well, you can remove the call to `print_r`, but you absolutely need the call to `sendEmail`.  So, just remove the characters `print_r(` and the final `)`.  You will surely want to give the user an indication that something happened.  Maybe `echo "<h2>Your mail was sent.</h2\n";`?

Comment: damn it was so easy, thanks so much!!!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)